# Assign html using jquery and get value from within form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

We have a jQuery dialog of the following form:

```
$("<div></div>").dialog({
    buttons: myButtons,
    close: function(event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
    resizable: false,
    title: title,
    modal: true,
    width: my_width
}).html(message);
```

This has worked great when the message is just text. However, now we want to include an input field in the message. We are having trouble accessing the value of the input field.

Here is the message:

```
'Enter some text.<br/><br/><form><input id="field1"></input></form>'
```

Our problem is that when we try to access the value of the input field using `document.getElementById('field1').value`, the DOM element apparently does not exist and we have not found a way to access the user's entry.

What do we need to do to get that value of that element after the user submits the dialog?

Comment: If you're closing the dialog before running the code, you won't be able to get the value, since you're calling `$(this).remove()`, which removes the elements from the DOM. You'll want to get the value in the `close` handler.

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as `</input>`. Input fields are self-closing.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - you hit the nail on the head. Please make this an answer instead of a comment, so I can give credit for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're closing the dialog before running the code, you won't be able to get the value, since you're calling `$(this).remove()`, which removes the elements from the DOM. You'll want to get the value in the `close` handler.